# How to transfrom a QRect to OpenGL coordinates?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have an app where a several `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`  needs to be blitted onto a larger `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`. In order to do so, I thought I could simply "paste" the fbos onto the large fbo using the standard coordinates in Qt. The [QOpenGLFramebufferObject::blitFramebuffer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#blitFramebuffer-2) requires a "source" rect and a "target" rect. So for example, if my large fbo is 1000x1000 and my smaller fbos are 500x500. Then I would simply need to do the following:

```
auto sourceRect = QRect(0,0,500,500);
// i here would be the row of my grid of fbos
// j would be the column
for(int i =0; i < 2; i++){
    for(int j= 0; j < 2; j++){
            auto targetRect = QRect(i*500,j*500, 500, 500);
            // tileFbo are the small fbos
            QOpenGLFramebufferObject::blitFramebuffer(largeFbo,targetRect, tileFbo,sourceRect)
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as it seems that QOpenGLFramebufferObject uses OpenGL coordinates. So how I can convert my QRect to use OpenGL coordinates?

Here is an example where I draw a line a small fbo (500x500) and then blit the small fbo on a large fbo (1000x1000). The line on the large fbo appears to be at the bottom-left instead of the top-left.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QOpenGLPaintDevice>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(8);
    QOffscreenSurface* surface = new QOffscreenSurface;
    surface->setFormat(format);
    surface->create();

    QOpenGLContext* context = new QOpenGLContext;
    if(!context->create()){
        qDebug() << "Failed to create context";
    }
    context->makeCurrent(surface);

    auto smallFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(QSize(500,500));
    auto largeFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(QSize(1000,1000));
    smallFbo->bind();
    QOpenGLPaintDevice paintDevice(smallFbo->size());
    QPainter painter(&paintDevice);
    painter.drawLine(QLine(0,0,400,400));
    smallFbo->release();
    // save small fbo to disk
    smallFbo->toImage().save("/home/Desktop/smallfbo.png");

    // blit the frame buffers
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject::blitFramebuffer(largeFbo, QRect(0,0,500,500), smallFbo, QRect(0,0,500,500));
    // save large fbo to disk
    largeFbo->toImage().save("/home/Desktop/largefbo.png");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that targetRect is `QRect(0,0,0,0)` at first iteration of the loop? For understanding the mechanism of that function it is better to try without loops, just try to blit one fbo to another with specific QRect's.

Comment: Actually the first rect woul have Coordinates (0,0,500,500) so in qt standard Coordinates it would be at the top-left with size 500. I have also tried without loops as well but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `"...it seems that QOpenGLFramebufferObject uses OpenGL coordinates"`?  Even if that were true the source and target would need to be specified by `QRectF` rather than `QRect`.

Comment: Because according to my testing, the fbos gets painted in seemingly "random" position (from my testing it seems that the (0,0) coordinates seems to be the bottom left of the large fbo). Why would `QRectF` make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, this function is everything you need

```
QRect to_OpenGL_coordinates(const QRect& qt_coordinateRect, const QOpenGLFramebufferObject& fbo){
    return QRect(qt_coordinateRect.x(), fbo.height() - qt_coordinateRect.y(),
                 qt_coordinateRect.width(), qt_coordinateRect.height() * -1);
}
```

and use it like this

```
// blit the frame buffers
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject::blitFramebuffer(largeFbo, to_OpenGL_coordinates(QRect(0,0,500,500), *largeFbo),
                                              smallFbo, to_OpenGL_coordinates(QRect(0,0,500,500), *smallFbo));
```

as a result.

[image]